# How Find youtube keyword using flutter dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

How find youtube keyword using https in flutter ?

```
Future getWebsiteData() async {
    dynamic url = Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ZfRE_DN9a0");
    dynamic response = await http.get(url);
    dom.Document html = dom.Document.html(response.body);

    final keywords = html
        .querySelectorAll('meta[name="keywords"]')
        .map((e) => e.innerHtml.trim())
        .toList();
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried using an existing package like https://pub.dev/packages/html to parse html.